# Updating Nulls

Tags: null, updating

I am trying to generate a data layer template. When I do my Selects, Updates, and Inserts, the idea is to have the template work with all the columns because I don't know which one's contain values or not. The problem is that I may have an update statemtent like cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field", this.Field); and if that value is null, the query won't execute. How can I get around this problem?

UPDATE:

I tried the ?? solution but I receive the error Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands string(or int) and System.DBNull. It seems to only work if the field is actually null, but not if it has a value. Then I tried to place the type (object)DBNull in front of DBNull but still nothing.

Adding (object) to this field worked!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Field", this.Field ?? DBNull.Value);
```

?? is the [coalesce operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) in C#.

Comment: I've tried this but I receive the error Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands string(and int) and System.DBNull

Comment: Try (object)this.Field ?? DBNull.Value